# Ajax with javascript not working on wamp server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wampserver

I am new to ajax and was following a youtube tutorial to create a simple food search app
where users enter food name in input field it shows the name below else it
 says that food not available
but somehow its not working on wamp server ..it shows the error alert instead

here is my code

index.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
  <title>Ajax app</title>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <style>

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="process()">

  <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput"/>
    <div id="underInput"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

foodstore.js

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttprequestObject();

function createXmlHttprequestObject()
    {
        var xmlHttp;
        if(window.ActiveXObject){

            try{
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(e){

                xmlHttp =false;
            }
        }else{

            try{
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch(e){

                xmlHttp =false;
            }

        }

        if(!xmlHttp){
            alert("can't create that object boss");
        }else{
            return xmlHttp;
        }
    }

    function process()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==0||xmlHttp.readyState==4){
             food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
             xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
             xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
             xmlHttp.send(null);
        }else{
             setTimeout("process()",1000);  
        }
    }
    function handleServerResponse()
    {    
    //readystate 4 whenever response is ready and object done communicating
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            //state 200 means communiaction went ok
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==200){
                xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
                xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
                message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
                document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue'>" + message + "</span>"
                setTimeout("process()",1000);   
            }else{
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }
```

foodstore.php

```
<?php
 header("Content-type: text/xml");
 echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>";

 echo "<response>";
    $food = $_GET["food"];
    $foodArray = array("tuna","bacon","beef","loaf","ham");
    if(in_array($food,$foodArray))
    {
        echo "We do have" .$food. "!";
    }
    elseif($food ="")
    {
        echo "Enter a food please.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"sorry but we don't even sell" . $food. "!";
    }
 echo "</response>";
?>
```

any help will be highly appreciated ,thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Good questions tend to solicit quick, great answers from the community

Comment: check your network->xhr tab in dev tools.

Comment: Which alert message does it show ? "something went wrong" or  "can't create that object boss" ?

Comment: @accountant "something went wrong"

Comment: @Sash_007 That means the server didn't response with `200 ok` status code, you need to check what is the response in your browser network tab.

Comment: @joel ..xhr tab shows nothing ..i see this https://imgur.com/NQ42hHz

Comment: Please don't include/use foul and demeaning/insulting language. You could have gotten flagged for it so I edited out.

Comment: @funk fortniner ..sorry ..willkeep that in mind ..it was in the tutorial tho ..thanks

Comment: Thanks man @Sash_007 :) Cheers and all the best in the New Year. I hope [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549640/1415724) below helped solve your code problem.

Comment: You have to open the inspector before the xhr request is sent, then you should see it show up and you can check the response and response codes.

Answer (score 1):

Please do *NOT* use `xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");`.  Your best bet is to combine [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp), but "ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")" is obsolete (even for Microsoft environments), and unsupported on many browsers.

Here's a [simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_http.asp) (no jQuery):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log('myArr', myArr);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
```

This syntax is supported on *ALL* contemporary browsers ... and has been supported by Microsoft since IE7 (since 2006).

ALSO:

You definitely want to learn about Chrome Developer Tools (part of the Chrome browser), if you're not already familiar with it:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools